# Can't find -ltcl83

Tags: python, compiling

I am running Ubuntu on Virtual Box and I'm very new to it, i'm trying to compile a bit of C code into a .py file but it cannont find -ltcl83

Using `locate libtcl` it returns `/usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so.0`

I don't know what to do or what other info to provide so please leave a comment about what else to include. Thanks.

update:

actual error returned is:

```
python.c: In function ‘Util_Autoload_from’:
python.c:376:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘chdir’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/python.o -L/usr/local/lib -ltcl83 -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/demo.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl83
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: From the name 83, I guess it wants 8.3 ... Try to find the older one somewhere, or modify the code so it uses the newer lib. | You could try installing older Debian packages... or Ubuntu ones. (Always backup.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are searching for a file, it's always a good idea to check out the [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and [Debian](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) repositories.

A [short search shows us](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libtcl8.3.so&mode=filename&suite=lucid&arch=any), that Lucid got the package we need.
From this, you can grab the binary packages. Install them, or just extract them.
You can even re-build the sources/grab them if you need to.

Just an extra bit of information: "dget" is a great tool. It grabs the source, the patches, and prepares the source in a folder, just like the binary package got it.

So you can recompile the files the way you want, and it will have the same Ubuntu/Debian patches.
(You can, of course, remove these patches if you want to.)
You can install dget by: `sudo apt-get install devscripts`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the tcl package. I think Ubuntu 12 comes with tcl 8.4.

So you have two possibilities: Either you replace -ltcl83 with -ltcl84 (But please be aware of possible side-effects!) or you search and install tcl 8.3 from an older Ubuntu distro.